# Python3 Pass parameters in the right order

Tags: python, python-3.x, encryption

Firstly, I am unsure how to title this as I can't think of how to even describe my issue. (let me know and I'll update the title when I can)

Well, What I am trying to do is make sure that the parameters being passed to a function aren't mixed up. This will be easier to understand with some code.. The following is the code I am working with.

```py
#clearing terminal.
def clear():
    os.system("clear||cls")


#Make master key for encrypting stuff.
def keygen(master):
    if len(master) < 100:
        clear()
        input('Password/characters used must be 100 characters in length or more!\n\nPress "eneter" to continue...')
        clear()
        return None
    else:
        salt = os.urandom(16)

        # derive | DO NOT MESS WITH...unless you know what you are doing and or have more than 8GB of ram to spare and a really good CPU.
        print("Generating key...")
        with alive_bar(0) as bar:
            key = argon2.hash_password_raw(
                time_cost=16,
                memory_cost=2**20,
                parallelism=4,
                hash_len=32,
                password=master,
                salt=salt,
                type=argon2.Type.ID
            )
            bar()
        clear()
        return key #returns bytes. You will need to base64 encode them yourself if you want a "shareable key"



# Encrypting the passwords with master key and AES encryption.
def stringE(data, key):
    cipher = AES.new(key, AES.MODE_GCM)
    cipher.update(header)
    ciphertext, tag = cipher.encrypt_and_digest(data)
    json_k = [ 'nonce', 'header', 'ciphertext', 'tag' ]
    json_v = [ b64.b64encode(x).decode('utf-8') for x in [cipher.nonce, header, ciphertext, tag ]]
    result = json.dumps(dict(zip(json_k, json_v)))
    result_bytes = bytes(result, 'utf-8')
    b64_result = b64.b64encode(result_bytes)
    return b64_result.decode()




#Encrypting
data = b'Hello World <3'
key_data = b'abcdeabcdeabcdeabcdeabcdeabcdeabcdeabcdeabcdeabcdeabcdeabcdeabcdeabcdeabcdeabcdeabcdeabcdeabcdeabcde'

eKey = keygen(key_data) #Returns bytes and will return "None" if what's provided is less than 100 characters.
save_me = base64.b64encode(eKey) #for saving eKey to decrypt later.

input(f'Save this key so you can decrypt later: {save_me}\n\nPress "enter" to contine...')
clear() #clears terminal or cmd/powershell window.

data_enc = stringE(data, eKey) #It is CRITICAL that you have the data you want to encrypt FIRST then the key.
clear()
print(data_enc) # Output is b64 encoded. --> eyJub25jZSI6ICJjQjhpWmc0MWhDWXBRVXdVdW53Q0pRPT0iLCAiaGVhZGVyIjogIlJXNWpjbmx3ZEdWa0lIVnphVzVuSUVkRFRXeHBZaTRnUkU4Z1RrOVVJRlJCVFZCRlVpQlhTVlJJTGlBZ2ZDQWdUV0ZrWlNCaWVTQjBhR1Z5WldGc1QzSnBJQ0I4SUNCaUoxeDRNVE5jZUdKaFhIaGpaVng0TVdWY2VHRTRYSGhsT1VOY2VHRmxKdz09IiwgImNpcGhlcnRleHQiOiAiZ2FDSjY4N2FGVjNMMEIyb01Ecz0iLCAidGFnIjogIkJBUjlmVzkzaWFESnUwckpSU2o3VEE9PSJ9
```

In this example code We have a KDF and an encryption function and some example usage at the bottom. My issue is that I DON'T want a user to pass to the function the data they want to encrypt as the key and the key as what they want to encrypt.

For `stringE(data, eKey)` If data is "`abc`" and eKey is "`xyz`", I don't want data to be "`xyz`" and eKey to be "`abc`". This can cause a big problem because "data" is what you want to have be encrypted and "eKey" are the bytes from the KDF to encrypt "data". If things get reversed then this can be bad and when you try to decrypt the "data"..you won't get the data you wanted to encrypt in the first place or it may error. I don't know how to solve this issue.

I would like to have a way to have what's passed to the function be what it is supposed to be and passed to the function in the correct order. I don't need the encrypt function to be working with 2 variables that are assigned the wrong data/mixing up the data and messing everything up. Hopefully what I am saying makes sense and is understandable. I just want the data for parameter 1 to be what it should be and the data for parameter 2 to also be what it should be.

If anyone can give some suggestions or can help, it'd be VERY appreciated! All I can think of is to have some if checks in the function itself to make sure, but I want to know if there are other/better ways to achieve what I want. Even if the answer it is a link to an already asked question that I couldn't find or didn't see, I'd still really appreciate it.

Comment: Use named arguments: `gcm.stringE(data="foo", key="bar")`

Comment: In general, it's up to the caller to know the order expected by the function. Keyword arguments make it *easier* to avoid mistakes, but nothing would prevent you from accidentally writing `gcm.stringE(data="bar", key="foo")`, either.

Comment: There are some additional things you can do with static typing, but that requires using a tool like `mypy` to catch the mistakes.

Comment: you can enforce keyword arguments using `*` eg. `def foo(*, a, b):` requires the function to be called as `foo(a=1, b=2)`, whereas `foo(1,2)` will throw a TypeError (as the arguments are positional rather than keyword)

Comment: @bn_ln That enforces the use of keyword arguments for those parameters; it doesn't keep you from swapping the values assigned to the parameters, though.

Comment: Why worry about it? If someone misuses the function then they misuse the function. The built-in function `pow()` works perfectly even though `pow(2,10)` is a bug even if it is meant to be `pow(10,2)`.  The function `pow` would be much less useful if the user was forced to write things like `pow(base = 10, exponent = 2)` in order to use it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no way to *prevent* this error, but there are a few things you can do to make such errors more obvious.

First, switch from regular parameters to keyword-only parameters:

```
def stringE(*, data, key):
    ...
```

`string(data="...", key="...")` may make it more obvious that you are attempting to specify a key as data or vice versa.

Second, use static type hints. Even though both parameters expect `str` values, you can use `typing.NewType` to create, well, new types to represent each.

```
from typing import NewType

Data = NewType("Data", str)
Key = NewType("Key", str)

def stringE(*, data: Data, key: Key):
    ...
```

At runtime, `stringE(data="...", key="...")` is still legal, but tools like `mypy` will reject it. It requires the two arguments be constructed using `Data` and `Key`, respectively, "forcing" the caller to do something like

```
stringE(data=Data('...'), key=Key('...'))
```

which could make it even more obvious when the wrong type of string is passed as an argument. At runtime, `Data` and `Key` simply return their argument, but the two are not interchangeable with `str` or with each other.

Taking this a step further, replace the new types with actual classes that can perform runtime tests on their arguments to ensure the data is correct. This requires you to have some runtime test that can distinguish the value of a string as a valid key or as valid data.

```
class Data:
    def __init__(self, d):
        ...


class Key:
    def __init__(self, d):
        ...


def stringE(*, data: Data, key: Key):
    ...


stringE(data=Data('...'), key=Key('...')
```

The difference here is that `Data.__init__` and `Key.__init__` can (unlike the `NewType`s above) do more to determine if `...` is actually a valid data or key.

Since the first thing `stringE` does with `key` is try to create a new `AES` object, consider requiring the *caller* to create that object, rather than passing an opaque `str` value.

```
aes_key = AES.new(eKey)
def stringE(*data, *cipher):
    ciphertext, tag = cipher.encrypt_and_digest(data)
    json_k = [ 'nonce', 'header', 'ciphertext', 'tag' ]
    json_v = [ b64.b64encode(x).decode('utf-8') for x in [cipher.nonce, header, ciphertext, tag ]]
    result = json.dumps(dict(zip(json_k, json_v)))
    result_bytes = bytes(result, 'utf-8')
    b64_result = b64.b64encode(result_bytes)
    return b64_result.decode()


aes_key = AES.new(eKey, AES.MODE_GCM)
aes_key.update(header)

data_enc = stringE(data=data, cipher=aes_key)
```